# How to list folders and projects inside the folders in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

In my GCP organization which has following hierarchy `Org--> folder--> folder--> folder--> projects--> Resources`.
I have a global view service account using which has necessary permission to list the projects and folders.
I am making use of GCP JAVA client library but I see listing folders I need to make use of `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v2/folders` which is under v2 Cloud resource Manager API but for listing projects I need `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects` which is under v1
Cloud resource Manager API.
Is there a way I can make use of GCP JAVA client library to list both folders and projects together??

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no single method that would allow to list both folders and projects.
If you think that function should be available, you can create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Alternatively, there is a [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852670/14663497) that utilizes gcloud commands for similar result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: "${ORGANIZATION:?Need to export ORGANIZATION and it must be non-empty}"

# gcloud format
FORMAT="csv[no-heading](name,displayName.encode(base64))"

# Enumerates Folders recursively
folders()
{
  LINES=("$@")
  for LINE in ${LINES[@]}
  do
    # Parses lines of the form folder,name
    VALUES=(${LINE//,/ })
    FOLDER=${VALUES[0]}
    # Decodes the encoded name
    NAME=$(echo ${VALUES[1]} | base64 --decode)
    echo "Folder: ${FOLDER} (${NAME})"
    folders $(gcloud resource-manager folders list \
      --folder=${FOLDER} \
      --format="${FORMAT}")
  done
}

# Start at the Org
echo "Org: ${ORGANIZATION}"
LINES=$(gcloud resource-manager folders list \
  --organization=${ORGANIZATION} \
  --format="${FORMAT}")

# Descend
folders ${LINES[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are asking for the most horrible API on Google Cloud. It's a bad and horrible API and your problem is the result of that... Anyway, I took several hours to try and I can propose you to use the Discovery API (so simple in python and very very few documented and hard to use in Java). Indeed, you can't use the autogenerated client library, you need to use the direct API call or the [Discovery API](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list)

Firtly, add this dependency in your Maven definition

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20190129-1.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then the Discovery API usage.

```
// Build the discovery API object
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        Discovery discovery = (new Discovery.Builder(httpTransport,jsonFactory,null)).build();

// Prepare your credential for the calls
        GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential));

// Discover the API V1 of resource manager
        RestDescription apiV1 = discovery.apis().getRest("cloudresourcemanager", "v1").execute();

// Discover the API V2 of resource manager
        RestDescription apiV2 = discovery.apis().getRest("cloudresourcemanager", "v2").execute();

//Get a Method in the v1, here list project
        RestMethod methodListProject = apiV1.getResources().get("projects").getMethods().get("list");

//Get a Method in the v2, here list folders
        RestMethod methodListFolder = apiV2.getResources().get("folders").getMethods().get("list");

/////////////////////// V1 call /////////////////////

//Create the URL to call, with no query parameter here
        GenericUrl urlProjectList = new GenericUrl(UriTemplate.expand(apiV1.getBaseUrl() + methodListProject.getPath(), null, true));
        System.out.println(urlProjectList);

//Prepare the request
        HttpRequest requestProjectList = requestFactory.buildRequest(methodListProject.getHttpMethod(), urlProjectList, null);

//Execute and print the result
        System.out.println(requestProjectList.execute().parseAsString());

/////////////////////// V2 call /////////////////////

//Prepare the parameter for the call    
        JsonSchema param = new JsonSchema();
        param.set(
                "parent", String.format("organizations/%s", "<OrganisationID>"));


//Create the URL to call, with the query parameter
        GenericUrl urlFolderList = new GenericUrl(UriTemplate.expand(apiV1.getBaseUrl() + methodListFolder.getPath(), param, true));
        System.out.println(urlFolderList);

//Prepare the request
        HttpRequest requestFolderList = requestFactory.buildRequest(methodListFolder.getHttpMethod(), urlFolderList, null);

//Execute and print the result
        System.out.println(requestFolderList.execute().parseAsString());
```

Both works in the same code, in the same time. Not very readable. I recommend you to wrap that in classes that fit your requirements for a better readability/reusability.

You need to use a lot the [API description](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest) to know and understand which methods exist and their parameters

Answer (score 0):

A python solution and description is published in [GCP Resource Manager - listing everything](https://blog.graunoel.com/resource-manager-list-all-projects) **by Joan Grau**.

The code works pretty well unmodified:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()

# V1 is needed to call all methods except for the ones related to folders
rm_v1_client = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False) 

# V2 is needed to call folder-related methods
rm_v2_client = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False) 

ORGANIZATION_ID = '[MY-ORG-ID]'

def listAllProjects():
    # Start by listing all the projects under the organization
    filter='parent.type="organization" AND parent.id="{}"'.format(ORGANIZATION_ID)
    projects_under_org = rm_v1_client.projects().list(filter=filter).execute()

    # Get all the project IDs
    all_projects = [p['projectId'] for p in projects_under_org['projects']]

    # Now retrieve all the folders under the organization
    parent="organizations/"+ORGANIZATION_ID
    folders_under_org = rm_v2_client.folders().list(parent=parent).execute()

    # Make sure that there are actually folders under the org
    if not folders_under_org:
        return all_projects

    # Now sabe the Folder IDs
    folder_ids = [f['name'].split('/')[1] for f in folders_under_org['folders']]

    # Start iterating over the folders
    while folder_ids:
        # Get the last folder of the list
        current_id = folder_ids.pop()
        
        # Get subfolders and add them to the list of folders
        subfolders = rm_v2_client.folders().list(parent="folders/"+current_id).execute()
        
        if subfolders:
            folder_ids.extend([f['name'].split('/')[1] for f in subfolders['folders']])
        
        # Now, get the projects under that folder
        filter='parent.type="folder" AND parent.id="{}"'.format(current_id)
        projects_under_folder = rm_v1_client.projects().list(filter=filter).execute()
        
        # Add projects if there are any
        if projects_under_folder:
            all_projects.extend([p['projectId'] for p in projects_under_folder['projects']])

    # Finally, return all the projects
    return all_projects

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(listAllProjects())
```

The only difference from the blog is that I created a custom role at the Org Level and applied that role to the service account. The role includes these Resource Manager permissions.

- resourcemanager.folders.get
- resourcemanager.folders.list
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.list

The above code fetches projects from sub folders but won't handle pagination if there are more projects or folders than the default pageSize. This could be an issue for large orgs.

I made some changes to handle the pagination. Note that I set pageSize=2 to test it works, but delete it to return to default in production.

This version of the function also returns a list of ids of all the folders that were discovered.

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def listAllProjects(credentials, ORGANIZATION_ID):
    # V1 is needed to call all methods except for the ones related to folders
    all_projects = []
    folder_ids = []

    rm_v1_client = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    # V2 is needed to call folder-related methods
    rm_v2_client = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v2', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

    # Start by listing all the projects under the organization
    filter='parent.type="organization" AND parent.id="{}"'.format(ORGANIZATION_ID)

    request = rm_v1_client.projects().list(pageSize=2, filter=filter)

    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        if response:
            projects_in_org_page = response['projects']
            # Get all the project IDs
            all_projects.extend(projects_in_org_page)
        request = rm_v1_client.projects().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

    # Now retrieve all the folders under the organization
    parent="organizations/"+ORGANIZATION_ID
    #folders_under_org = rm_v2_client.folders().list(parent=parent).execute()

    request = rm_v2_client.folders().list(pageSize=2, parent=parent)

    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        if response:
            # Now save the Folder IDs
            folder_ids_in_page = [f['name'].split('/')[1] for f in response['folders']]
            # Get all the project IDs
            folder_ids.extend(folder_ids_in_page)
        request = rm_v2_client.folders().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

    # Make sure that there are actually folders under the org
    if not folder_ids:
        return all_projects, folder_ids

    found_folder_ids = folder_ids.copy() # because folder_ids will be popped till it empties
    # Start iterating over the folders
    while folder_ids:
        # Get the last folder of the list
        current_id = folder_ids.pop()
        # Get subfolders and add them to the list of folders
        subfolders = rm_v2_client.folders().list(pageSize=2, parent="folders/"+current_id).execute()

        if subfolders:
            folder_ids.extend([f['name'].split('/')[1] for f in subfolders['folders']])
            found_folder_ids.extend(folder_ids_in_page)

        request = rm_v2_client.folders().list(pageSize=2, parent="folders/"+current_id)
        while request is not None:
            response = request.execute()
            if response:
                # Now save the Folder IDs
                folder_ids_in_page = [f['name'].split('/')[1] for f in response['folders']]
                # Get all the project IDs
                folder_ids.extend(folder_ids_in_page)
                found_folder_ids.extend(folder_ids_in_page)
            request = rm_v2_client.folders().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

        # Now, get the projects under that folder
        filter='parent.type="folder" AND parent.id="{}"'.format(current_id)
        projects_under_folder = rm_v1_client.projects().list(filter=filter).execute()
        request =  rm_v1_client.projects().list(filter=filter)

        while request is not None:
            response = request.execute()
            if response:
                projects_under_folder_page = response['projects']
                # Get all the project IDs
                all_projects.extend(projects_under_folder_page)
            request = rm_v1_client.projects().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

    # Finally, return all the projects
    return all_projects, found_folder_ids
```