# My gcloud query fetches 2 sets of values, how do I display them separately?

Tags: bash, gcloud

The following gcloud query (somewhat) returns all the GCP folders within an organization:

```sh
ORG=$(\
  gcloud organizations list \
  --format="value(name)")
FOLDERS=$(\
  gcloud resource-manager folders list \
  --format="value(ID,displayName)" \
  --organization=${ORG})

for FOLDER in ${FOLDERS}
do
  echo ${FOLDER}
done
```

1. How do I echo the folder IDs and folder displayNames separately?
2. Also, the folder displayNames contain whitespaces. I presume I'd need to use base64 encoding + decoding to display them correctly. But I don't know how to do that.

Can someone please guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to this has been to output CSV from the `gcloud` command that's providing the loop's range using `format="csv(ID,displayName)` to give values that are comma-separated and then use `IFS` and `read` to split the string into the 2 fields

In your `for` loop you can use:

```
IFS=, read ID DISPLAY_NAME <<< ${FOLDER}
```

IIRC your can `--format="csv(ID, displayName.encode(base64))"` to encode `displayName` and then use bash's `base64 --decode` to decode it. I have an example on here <strike>somewhere using it with `gcloud` but am on my phone and it's less easy to search.</strike>

Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852670/609290

By the way, these functions are all documented -- albeit not easy to find -- as [gcloud topic projections](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections)